# Raspberry PI 1B: Multiple "Push Buttons"

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I use a Raspi 1B which are connected 15 buttons + 1 led. Each button represents a letter box, the time press determines the contents of the box (letters, packages and special) and calls the appropriate bash script to send an email. Currently I have several python scripts (15, one for each button) that I will wish to merge into one script but I can not.

Here's what the script looks like (one of the 15 scripts):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

from time import sleep
import subprocess

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# GPIO 2 (pin 3)
CHANNEL = 2

# durees
colis = 2
special = 4

# GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(CHANNEL, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

# LED
GPIO.setup(18,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)

# fonction de gestion du bouton
def system_button(CHANNEL):

# variable de stockage du temps de pression
button_press_timer = 0

while True:
   if (GPIO.input(CHANNEL) == False) :
      button_press_timer += 0.2
         GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)

   else:
      if (button_press_timer > special) :
         print "special : ", button_press_timer
         subprocess.call("./Special.sh", shell=True)
         GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)

      elif (button_press_timer > colis) :
         print "colis : ", button_press_timer
         subprocess.call("./Colis.sh", shell=True)
         GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)

      elif (button_press_timer > 0.2):
         print "lettre : ", button_press_timer
         subprocess.call("./Lettre.sh", shell=True)
         GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)

      button_press_timer = 0

   sleep(0.2)

GPIO.add_event_detect(CHANNEL, GPIO.FALLING, callback=system_button, bouncetime=200)

try:
while True:

   sleep (2)

except KeyboardInterrupt:

GPIO.cleanup()

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: I could combine all the scripts for you send me an email at thesonyman101@gmail.com